# Magento Fatal Error when editing customer accounts

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have Magento 1.7.0.2 and when I try to edit a customer account in the admin panel i get this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function setRenderer() on a non-object in /home/techspec/public_html/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account.php on line 77

```
 $attributes = $customerForm->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        /* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
        $attribute->setFrontendLabel(Mage::helper('customer')->__($attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel()));
        $attribute->unsIsVisible();
    }

    $disableAutoGroupChangeAttributeName = 'disable_auto_group_change';
    $this->_setFieldset($attributes, $fieldset, array($disableAutoGroupChangeAttributeName));

    $form->getElement('group_id')->setRenderer($this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_renderer_attribute_group')
        ->setDisableAutoGroupChangeAttribute($customerForm->getAttribute($disableAutoGroupChangeAttributeName))
        ->setDisableAutoGroupChangeAttributeValue($customer->getData($disableAutoGroupChangeAttributeName)));

    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $form->getElement('website_id')->setDisabled('disabled');
        $form->getElement('created_in')->setDisabled('disabled');
    } else {
        $fieldset->removeField('created_in');
        $form->getElement('website_id')->addClass('validate-website-has-store');
```

That is line 67 to 87 of the referenced file. Would love any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

looks like the attribute `group_id` is not in your list of editable attributes. Make sure the attribute is visible. Use this select to check.

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` e 
LEFT JOIN `customer_eav_attribute` ce ON e.attribute_id = ce.attribute_id 
WHERE e.attribute_code = 'group_id'
```

See the value of field `is_visible`.

If you don't get any result from the query above then you are in trouble.

If that is 1, maybe the attribute is not set to be shown in the admin form. Get the `attribute_id` returned by the previous query and do this. Let's say the value is `10`.

```
select * from customer_form_attribute where attribute_id = 10;
```

If there is no record with `form_code` = `adminhtml_customer` then you should add it.